# Node js command line doesn't work on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, command-line

I've built a command line using Nodejs, I was developing it on windows, than after I published it on npm, I installed it from Ubuntu, then I tried to use it, it says that there is no such file.

I'm not sure of what is the problem, I have doubt that it's from this line :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

I also tried to clone the repo from ubuntu, and I run the command

```
npm link
```

and it worked ! can someone please tell me what did I do wrong ?

Here is the whole repo on [github](https://github.com/Javascipt/detail) and the package on [npm](http://npmjs.com/package/detail)

Comment: I know that Ubuntu has issue with links. Did you try run `node -v` and `npm -v`? What it says?

Comment: on my windows it says for `node` v4.1.0 and `npm` v2.14.3 . but I don't have ubuntu now. I tested it yesterday on another computer ...

Comment: Update your question with full stack trace of the error then.

Comment: On your `bin` property in `package.json`, perhaps try `./index.js` instead of just `index.js`.

Comment: I did it , but still doesn't work.